# Convert HTML Table to plain Text in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am a beginner in power BI. I have to create a report with share point data.  I have imported the data into dataset. However, some columns have text with html table tags or style like below -

```html
<div class="ExternalClass5DA0D04953B047459697675F266FEABF">
   <p>​</p>
   <table width="395" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width&#58;296pt;">
  <tbody>
     <tr height="115" style="height&#58;86.4pt;">
        <td width="395" height="115" class="xl64" style="width&#58;296pt;height&#58;86.4pt;">
        I am working on issue. I shall update the progress.&#160;<br>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
   <p><br></p>
</div>
```

But I would like to show the plain text only which is "I am working on issue. I shall update the progress."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [community thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Removing-HTML-Script-from-data-in-Query-Editor/td-p/351995), you can find a [handy function](https://github.com/ImkeF/M/blob/master/Library/Text.RemoveHtmlTags.pq) for stripping all the HTML tags:

Here's the core logic (ignoring the documentation metadata for readability):

```
let func = (HTML) =>
    let 
        Check = if Value.Is(Value.FromText(HTML), type text) then HTML else "",
        Source = Text.From(Check),
        SplitAny = Text.SplitAny(Source,"<>"),
        ListAlternate = List.Alternate(SplitAny,1,1,1),
        ListSelect = List.Select(ListAlternate, each _<>""),
        TextCombine = Text.Combine(ListSelect, "")
    in
        TextCombine
 in 
    func
```

Having this handy bit of code, create a new blank query and paste the above code into the advanced editor and give it a name, say, `TextFromHTML`.

Once you have that function defined, you can use it in any of your queries. For example, here's what a step to transform the column `ColWithHTML` might look like:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Prior Step", {{"ColWithHTML", each TextFromHTML(_), type text}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with below formula as show below

```
if [HMTLField] = null then null else   Html.Table([HMTLField] , {{"text",":root"}})
```

[image]

Then click on the button on right top of the field to convert this field as text by expanding it.

[image]