# Convert HTML column to plain text in Power BI

Tags: html, powerbi, data-conversion

Power Bi imports (e.g. from Outlook calendar) some data with HTML tags.

I need to remove these and the simplest method is to create a custom column using Html.Table

```
Html.Table([HTML text],{{"Plain text",":root"}})
```

where "Plain text" is the new column.

This works fine, except if there are empty cells in the "HTML text" column. The first empty cell (null) causes an error:

```
"We cannot convert the value null to type Text"
```

And the conversion stops.

Is there a condition that can be applied "If null then null else" to solve this error?

Many thanks!

P.S. I have seen @Alexis Olson thread [Convert HTML Table to plain Text in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329169/convert-html-table-to-plain-text-in-power-bi) but the Html.Table solution is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the HTML is in a column titled Description, you can use the FieldValuesAsText column to convert the column to text:

1. Open the query editor (Transform data).
2. Remove the Description column.
3. Scroll right and select the expander icon for the “FieldValuesAsText” column.
4. Deselect all available fields except the “Description” column.
5. Deselect the “Use original column name as prefix” option.

[image: screenshot]

6. Select OK.

You now have a Description column free of all HTML formatting tags.

Consider duplicating the “FieldValuesAsText” column before using the only one in the dataset!

Solution by John White – full description here:
https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2018/04/power-bi-report-rich-text-sharepoint/#comment-55053

Answer (score 0):

You would right click on the column, replace Error as "null" and then Expand the Table created by the HTML function above and you should have no query performance problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).